# PDE transport equation please help

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Transport equation:
$$
\begin{cases}
 \frac{d}{dt}u +cu = 0\qquad    \mbox{ in } \mathbb{R}^n\times  (0,\infty) \\
u(x,0) = 0     \qquad       \mbox{ on }\mathbb{R}^n\times \{t=0\} 
\end{cases}
$$

b-const

Comment: What is the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 1):

**hint** Consider the integral curve $\gamma: (0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}^n$ given by $$\gamma(s) = (sb_1,sb_2,\ldots, sb_n)$$

then

$$\frac{d}{ds} u(s,\gamma(s)) = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u + b\cdot\nabla u\right)(s,\gamma(s))$$

and your equation becomes the ordinary differential equation along the curves $\gamma$ given by $\frac{d}{ds} u(s,\gamma(s)) = - cu$.

Comment: @user7224: pretty much: you will have $u(s,\gamma(s)) = u(0,\gamma(0)) \exp (-cs)$. So now you just need to match $u(0,\gamma(0))$ to your initial data.

Comment: For your most recent edit: if the initial data given is identically vanishing, then the only solution to the transport equation is that $u$ vanishes everywhere.